# How to flag an id which has repeated more than once in the past

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to flag an employee id with specific conditions which has repeated in the last 6 months. The way I want to do this is create a new column which will flag these employees with the conditions I have specified in the query

```
   Eeid  Receiveddt  Status  Reason  Past 6 months?
   123     May19     closed   OHM      1
   234     Jan19     closed   xyz      0
   123     July19    closed   OHM      1
   567     Aug19     open     ZZZ      0
   123     Sept19    open     OHM      0
```

Now as per the above example eeid 123 is flagged under column 'Past 6 months?' because the received date is in the last 6 months and the status was closed (these are my 2 conditions for flagging) 
I was thinking of using a case when statement but not sure how to check the repeated 'Eeid'

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       ( received_date > current_date - interval '6 month' and status = 'closed' )::int
from t;
```

Comment: I am unable to view the part of the query after : : I don't know if it got truncated, weird

Comment: @KaranKashyap . . . It is just `::int`.

Answer (score 0):

I read your requirement somewhat differently. I read it meaning you wanted to update the 'closed' rows having another of the same id also closed within a 6 month period closed within a 6 month period. The following does that, and I tried to structure it to show the step-by-step development (it could likely be reduced somewhat - but that wouldn't show its development). Hope this helps now and gives you technique to build upon.

```
update t
   set last_6mo_flag = 1
 where last_6mo_flag = 0
   and (id, received_date) in 
       (select id,received_date 
          from (select  id, received_date, last_6mo
                  from ( select id, received_date 
                              , (   coalesce((extract (days from (received_date + interval '6 months') - received_date)::integer) >  abs(next_date - received_date),false) 
                                 or coalesce((extract (days from (received_date + interval '6 months') - received_date)::integer) >  abs(prior_date- received_date),false)
                                ) last_6mo 
                           from (select id, received_date, status
                                      , lag(t.received_date)  over(partition by t.id order by t.id, t.received_date) next_date
                                      , lead(t.received_date) over(partition by t.id order by t.id, t.received_date) prior_date 
                                   from t
                                  where status = 'closed'                                   
                                ) s1 

                       ) s2
                 where last_6mo
               ) s3
       );
```